# Creating a Class type based on a generic type

Tags: java, generics

I know that I can do this:

```
Class<T> type = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

But how can I create a class based on this new type?

```
Class<MyObject<T>> type = ???;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Class<MyObject<T>> type = (Class<MyObject<T>>)(Class<?>)MyObject.class;
```

Comment: It will create the T object as a LinkedHashMap and not with the specific type.